# Stack has not been tested with GHC & Cabal versions

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

In my Haskell project when I `stack run`, it is showing the following, but still runs. What warning is this? How can I get rid of it?

```
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.2, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
```

Comment: This is just a compatibility warning. The next `stack` version should be tested with GHC 8.8 and this warning should be gone. Until then there's probably little you can do unless you want to modify the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a compatibility warning. The next stack version should be tested with GHC 8.8 and this warning should be gone. Until then there's probably little you can do unless you want to modify the source.

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, this can be most likely be ignored. If you want to be on the super-safe side, edit your stack.yaml and downgrade the resolver back to 14.x (latest at this point is 14.27).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a resolver when creating a project to get rid of this warning:

```
stack new hello-world simple --resolver=lts-14.27
```

Answer (score 0):

This may cause other warnings you actually care about to be suppressed, but if you run `stack --verbosity error` or `stack --silent` you won't see these warnings. For example

```
stack --verbosity error exec <your program>
```